# SequenceMatcher ratio return

Tags: python, string, comparison, difflib, sequencematcher

For example,
`a = 'OrangeApple'` and `b = 'AppleOrange'`, after running `SequenceMatcher(None, a, b).ratio()` the returned ratio (similarity score) is 0.54.
If `a = 'OrangeApple'` and `b = 'OrangeApple'` the returned ratio is, as expected, 1.

I somehow understand why this happens after reading [How does Pythons SequenceMatcher work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35517353/how-does-pythons-sequencematcher-work), but still not sure how to solve this issue to obtain a ratio equal to 1 in both cases. Any ideas?

Comment: if you had `b = 'eOarpgnAelp'` which ratio would you expect?

Comment: I would like to obtain 1 as well